# How to dynamically create a navigation based on Front Matter for Jekyll?

Tags: navigation, jekyll, liquid

Goals:

- Dynamic creation/management of a navigation without managing a data file
- Support overridable ordering
- Nesting of Elements
- Hidden page support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple way to dynamically manage documentation through front matter without the need for a pesky config file.

Three variables one can set in front matter:

- `parent`: Represents if this should be nested within another page for navigation
- `hidden`: `false` for a page to be publicly listed, it'll be accessible via direct link regardless
- `nav_priority`: Weights which document to show first, 1 is highest (ie top)

#### Logic

- Can default to hide/show everything within `_config.yml`
- A page shows up as a header if it:

  - has no parent OR
  - is a parent page
- If a page has a parent, it will show up underneath the parent

  - Can only have 2 levels
- If a parent is hidden, then all child pages are also hidden
- Weighting can be defaulted for documents in `_config.yml` to `100` to keep them at the bottom, or `1` for at top

*the below assumes the files are in `_docs` if elsewhere change `site.docs` accordingly*

```html
{% assign pages = site.docs | where: 'hidden', false %}
{% if pages.size > 0 %}
  {% assign head_pages = pages | where: 'parent', nil | sort: 'nav_priority' %}
  {% for head_page in head_pages %}
    <h5>
      <a href="{{ head_page.url }}">{{ head_page.title }}</a>
    </h5>

    <ul>
      {% assign child_pages = pages | where: 'parent', head_page.title | sort: 'nav_priority' %}
      {% for child in child_pages  %}
        <li>
          <a href="{{ child.url }}">{{ child.title }}</a>
        </li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```